# How to efficiently remove table from docx/xml and extract text

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've a problem with extracting text out of .docx after removing table.
The docx files I'm dealing with contain a lot of tables that I would like to get rid of before extracting the text.
I first use docx2html to convert a docx file to html, and then use BeautifulSoup to remove the table tag and extract the text.

```
from docx2html import convert
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
temp = convert(FileToConvert)
soup = BeautifulSoup(temp)
for i in range(0,len(soup('table'))):
    soup.table.decompose()
Text = soup.get_text()
```

While this process works and produces what I need, there is some efficiency issue with docx2html.convert(). Since .docx files are in infact .xml files, would it be possible to skip the the procedure of converting docx into html and just extract text from the xml after removing tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docx files are not just xml files but rather a [zipped xml based format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), so you won't be able to pass a docx file directly to BeautifulSoup. The format seems pretty simple though [as the zipped docx contains a file called *word/document.xml*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats#Container) which is probably the xml file you want to parse. You can use Python's zipfile module to extract this file and pass its contents directly to BeautfulSoup:

```
import sys
import zipfile

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], 'r') as zfp:
    with zfp.open('word/document.xml') as fp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), 'xml')

print soup
```

However, you might also want to look at https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx, which might do a lot of what you want already. I haven't tried it so I can't vouch for its suitability for your specific use-case.

Comment: You were right about python-docx. It does take care of extracting text from .docx files. After passing a docx to python-docx, a lxml.etree.Element is generated, which can be manipulated with lxml parsers.